# GWT: how to use Locale.ENGLISH in client side?

Tags: java, gwt, locale, emulation

I have a legacy class which contains `toLowerCase( Locale.ENGLISH )`

And when I use this class in my client side, I gets

```
[ERROR] [onboardingtool] Line 37: The method toLowerCase() in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (Locale)
```

But when I check GWT doc, it seems like `ROOT`, `US` and `ENGLISH` are already supported.
Here is the link: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html (search for "LOCALE")

I am using GWT 2.6.1. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Locale` is only supported in GWT 2.7.0 (RC1) and up.

[Here are the release notes of GWT 2.7.0 (RC1)](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_7_0_RC1), specifically:

"New emulated classes: **`Locale`**, `NavigableSet`, and `NavigableMap`"

and

"New emulated methods in `Class`, **`String`**, ..."

---

If you're using GWT 2.6.1, `Locale` and `String#toLowerCase(Locale)` won't be available.